# Three.js error when adding more than 37 spotlights to scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating a system using Three.js r58 (using the WebGLRenderer) showing a 3D model of a building with the actual positions and dim levels of the lights within.

Each light from the database is represented by a CubeGeometry object (the physical light) and a SpotLight (to show a semblance of what the light is outputting) created as follows:

```
// 'this' is an existing custom object as populated from the database - all code there is fine
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(4.8, 0.6, 1.36);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x444444, vertexColors:THREE.FaceColors});

this.objectMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
this.objectMesh.position.set(0, 20, 0);

scene.add(this.objectMesh);

this.lightEmitter = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 0, 22, true);
this.lightEmitter.position.set(this.objectMesh.position.x, this.objectMesh.position.y - (this.objectMesh.geometry.height / 10), this.objectMesh.position.z);
this.lightEmitter.rotation.set(this.objectMesh.rotation.x, this.objectMesh.rotation.y, this.objectMesh.rotation.z)
this.lightEmitter.target.position.set(this.objectMesh.position.x, 0, this.objectMesh.position.z);
this.lightEmitter.angle = 0.9;
scene.add(this.lightEmitter);
```

Now, everything was working perfectly with up to 37 lights in the scene, but as soon as I add light number 38 I receive the following error: `Could not initialise shader
VALIDATE_STATUS: false, gl error [1285]`

This error is seen in Firefox and Chrome on a Windows 7 PC with a GeForce GTX 650, as well as Firefox on an Ubuntu laptop (not sure of the graphics card but can find out if needed). On Chrome on an Android Nexus 7 I get an additional error: `(0) : error C6007: Constant register limit exceeded; more than 256 constant registers needed to compiled program
50 lines, 1 errors` - not sure if this is related or not.

If I remove the building model from the scene and load in a flat plane I also get: `ERROR: too many uniforms` with 38 lights, with 37 it works normally. I have also tried preventing lights and objects from casting and receiving shadows but it didn't help.

Am I hitting a hardware and/or OpenGL and/or WebGL limitation by rendering so many lights in the scene? If not does anyone have an idea of what may be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In forward rendering OpenGL ES (and WebGL) have a limit on the number of lights in the that are concurrently on. These limit is usually 8 so I am surprised you got up to 37. Things change with deferred rendering where you can have as many lights as you want. So instead of using the `WebGLRenderer` use the `WebGLDeferredRenderer.`

Comment: I forgot to mention that not all lights were on at the same time. At the time of writing the question 6 lights were on, and whether the next light was on or off would still give the same errors, although I currently have 16 lights on without error in that building model, and a different building model using the exact same code with 20+ lights on at the same time.

Comment: @gaitat: there is a limit to the number of lights you can use in the fixed pipeline shader, but Threejs does not use it (I don't think the fixed pipeline is available in WebGL anyway). Winterblood: you simply have reached an hardware limit => each time you use a light, threejs needs to allocate some registers to handle it (for light position, color, ...), and the number of registers available is limited by your graphics card. Not much you can do, except by creating only lights that are on and discarding the others, so that at any time there are only a few lights to handle (say less than 10).